# Trying to put an if-statement in a for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to input an if-statement inside of this for-loop so that whenever the user still has to eat the loop can be redone without having to lose the data already provided.

```
boolean yes = true;
                       boolean no = false;
                       double calorieCount = DCN;
                       int snackCalories = 300;
                       int mealCalories = 1100;
                       double meal = mealCalories;
                       double snack = snackCalories;
    for (int i = 1; calorieCount <= calorieCount; calorieCount--) {
                           System.out.println("Did you eat? yes or no");
                           String answer = sc.next();

                        if(yes == true) { //You did eat 
                               System.out.println("Did you eat a meal(1) or a snack(2)?");
                               int foodChoice = sc.nextInt();
                               if(foodChoice == 1) //Meal 
                               System.out.println("Your calories left for the day : " + (calorieCount - meal));
                                }
                               int foodChoice = sc.nextInt();
                                if(foodChoice == 2) {//Snack                  
                               calorieCount = calorieCount - snack;
                               System.out.println("Your calories left for the day : " + (calorieCount - snack));
                               }
                               else {
                               System.out.println("Your calories left for the day : " + calorieCount);
                               };
                               else(no == false){
                                   System.out.println(calorieCount);
                               }
```

Comment: May I ask why you just made duplicates of true (yes) and false (no)? It looks like you are somehow thinking that these have something to do with what the user inputs. You get input from the user, but rather than checking their answer, you check if yes == true (of course it is, you defined it that way). You probably want to check answer.equals("yes").

Comment: I'm still new to java

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you have some real syntax & semantic problems. For example your for-loop condition is calorieCount <= calorieCount. Both sides are equal. Overall its hard to read your Code because its not formatted correctly. Its hard to help right now - use a formatting Tool - Check Syntax and use a Debugger. Then clarify your question. Naming of your variables could also be improved.